# List regions that are actively been used within an organization in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have an organization in GCP, with multiple projects in it. Is there a gcloud command or REST API available, to list the regions that are actively been used within an organization??

Comment: have you already tried using [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) with the gcloud command
"gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope organizations/[ORG_ID] | grep zone" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "actively" used?

Comment: @Siegfred V   - I have tried asset inventory, but was wondering if there is any other way to capture the regions used by all resources in an organization

Comment: If you have tried something put that in your question. Show the results and why this does not solve your problem. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Security Command Center API](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/reference/rest/v1/organizations.assets/list)'s `organizations.assets.list` and [Cloud Asset Inventory API](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets/list)'s `assets.list`.

You may still need to use a programming language for the region filter.